# Bitlocker recovery key after motherboard replacement

Tags: laptop, motherboard, bitlocker

If I suspend the BitLocker before the replacement of motherboard of my laptop, would it ask for **BitLocker-recovery-key** if I turn on the laptop after motherboard's replacement?

Comment: It should not because you are writing the key to the HDD.  However, a boot configuration will still be possible, so you should KNOW your recovery key so you can provide it regardless. It also depends on which other BitLocker protectors you have enabled.